# Choosing the minumum distance

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'id': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'time_order': ['2019-01-01 0:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:11:00', '2019-01-02 00:04:00', '2019-01-02 00:15:00', '2019-01-03 00:07:00', '2019-01-03 00:10:00']}

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_data['time_order'] = pd.to_datetime(df_data['time_order'])
df_data['day_order'] = df_data['time_order'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df_data['time'] = df_data['time_order'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

I have been trying to calculate the short time difference between the orders each 15 minutes, e.g.
I take a time window `15 minutes` and take only its half `7:30` which means I would like to calculate the difference between the first order `'2019-01-01 0:00:00'` and `00:07:30` and between the second order `'2019-01-01 0:11:00'` and `00:07:30` and take only the order that is closer to `00:07:30` each day.

I did the following:

```
t = 0
x = '00:00:00'
y = '00:15:00'
g = 0
a = []
for i in range(1, len(df_data)):
    g +=1
    half_time = (pd.Timestamp(y) - pd.Timstamp(x).to_pydatetime()) / 2
    half_window = (half_time + pd.Timestamp(x).to_pydatetime()).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    for l in df_data['day_order']:
        for k in df_data['time_order']:
            if l == k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                distance1 = abs(pd.Timestamp(df_data.iat[i-1, 4].to_pydatetime() - pd.Timestamp(half_window).to_pydatetime())
                distance2 = abs(pd.Timestamp(df_data.iat[i, 4].to_pydatetime() - pd.Timestamp(half_window).to_pydatetime())
                if distance1 < distance2:
                    d = distance1 
                else:
                    d = distance2
    a.append(d.seconds)
```

so the expected result for the first day is `abs(00:11:00 - 00:07:30) = 00:03:30` which is less than `abs(00:00:00 - 00:07:30) = 00:07:30` and by doing so I would like to consider only the short time distance which means the `00:03:30` and ignor the first order at that day. I would like to do it for each day. I tried it with my code above, it doesn't work. Any idea would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Should the 15 min time winodws always start at 0:00:00 or for each day at the first order?

Comment: `2019-01-01 00:15:00  2019-01-01  00:15:00` what should happen to this entry on day1.

Comment: right, it should start from 00:00:00

Comment: @RishabhKumar, apologise it was a typo. I just have fixed it.

Comment: @Amir, okay I thought I didn't got the question, but now after your fix I get it. One more question, how do you want the final output to be?

Comment: @RishabhKumar, the answer is perfect. Thank you very much!

Comment: @RishabhKumar, I just have edited the code above, so that I move the time window each minute, e.g. from ```00:00:00``` - ```00:15:00``` to ```00:01:00```- ```00:16:00``` and look inside this period for the short distance, as previously discribed, and ignor other times that does not belong to that window. I tired to do this procedure for 30 minutes and it worked with your suggested solution. However, it took other times that does not belong to that period of time. Any ideas? Thank you

Comment: Hey, Glad it helped. As your requirements have changed, its better to start a new question. And as you have edited the question, you can even rollback, to the previous edit. After you ask this new question, tag me here and send me the new link.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Here is the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66560355/choosing-the-minumum-distance-part-2

Comment: Hey @RishabhKumar, I was just wondering whether you have had a look at the new question? Looking forward to hearing from you soon.

Comment: Hi, I didn't received the notification, cause I wasn't tagged in your previous comment. This time you tagged, so I got the notification.

Comment: I am sorry about that. I don't know how this platform works since I am new here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about the format of the expected output, but I would try to bring the result to a point where you can extract data as you like:

Loading given data:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'id': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'time_order': ['2019-01-01 0:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:11:00', '2019-01-02 00:04:00', '2019-01-02 00:15:00', '2019-01-03 00:07:00', '2019-01-03 00:10:00']}

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_data['time_order'] = pd.to_datetime(df_data['time_order'])
df_data['day_order'] = df_data['time_order'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df_data['time'] = df_data['time_order'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

---

Calculating difference:

```
x = '00:00:00'
y = '00:15:00'
diff = (pd.Timedelta(y)-pd.Timedelta(x))/2
```

Creating a new column 'diff' as timedelta:

```
df_data['diff'] = abs(df_data['time'] - diff)
```

Grouping (based on date) and apply:

```
mins = df_data.groupby('day_order').apply(lambda x: x[x['diff']==min(x['diff'])])
```

Removing Index (optional):

```
mins.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
```

Output DataFrame:

```
>>> mins
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:03:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:04:00  2019-01-02  00:04:00 0 days 00:03:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:07:00  2019-01-03  00:07:00 0 days 00:00:30
```

Making list of difference in seconds:

```
a = list(mins['diff'].apply(lambda x:x.seconds))
```

Output:

```
>>> a
[210, 210, 30]
```