# Choosing the minumum distance part 2

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

This question is already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66490797/choosing-the-minumum-distance?noredirect=1#comment117648272_66490797), but now I have added an extra part to the previous question.

I have the following dataframe:

```
data = {'id': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'time_order': ['2019-01-01 0:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:11:00', '2019-01-02 00:04:00', '2019-01-02 00:15:00', '2019-01-03 00:07:00', '2019-01-03 00:10:00']}

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_data['time_order'] = pd.to_datetime(df_data['time_order'])
df_data['day_order'] = df_data['time_order'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df_data['time'] = df_data['time_order'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
```

I have been trying to calculate the short time difference between the orders each 15 minutes, e.g. I take a time window 15 minutes and take only its half 7:30 which means I would like to calculate the difference between the first order '2019-01-01 0:00:00' and 00:07:30 and between the second order '2019-01-01 0:11:00' and 00:07:30 and take only the order that is closer to 00:07:30 each day.

I did the following:

```
t = 0
s = pd.Time.datetime.fromtimestamp(t).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
#x = '00:00:00'
#y = '00:15:00'
tw = 900
g = 0
a = []
for k in range(30):
    begin = pd.Timestamp(s).to_pydatetime()
    begin1 = begin + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(k*60))
    last = begin1 + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(tw))
    x = begin1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    y = last.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

    for i in range(1, len(df_data)):
        #g +=1
        if x <= df_data.iat[i-1, 4] <= y:

    
            half_time = (pd.Timestamp(y) - pd.Timstamp(x).to_pydatetime()) / 2
            half_window = (half_time + pd.Timestamp(x).to_pydatetime()).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
            for l in df_data['day_order']:
                for k in df_data['time_order']:
                    if l == k.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
                    distance1 = abs(pd.Timestamp(df_data.iat[i-1, 4].to_pydatetime() - pd.Timestamp(half_window).to_pydatetime())
                    distance2 = abs(pd.Timestamp(df_data.iat[i, 4].to_pydatetime() - pd.Timestamp(half_window).to_pydatetime())
                    if distance1 < distance2:
                        d = distance1 
                    else:
                        d = distance2
        a.append(d.seconds)
```

so the expected result for the first day is abs(00:11:00 - 00:07:30) = 00:03:30 which is less than abs(00:00:00 - 00:07:30) = 00:07:30 and by doing so I would like to consider only the short time distance which means the 00:03:30 and ignor the first order at that day. I would like to do it for each day. I tried it with my code above, it doesn't work. Any idea would be very appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Update:
I just have added an extra command to the code above, so that I move the time window each minute, e.g. from 00:00:00 - 00:15:00 to 00:01:00- 00:16:00 and look inside this period for the short distance, as previously discribed, and ignor other times that does not belong to that window. I tired to do this procedure for 30 minutes and it worked with your suggested solution. However, it took other times that does not belong to that period of time.

Comment: Hi, you said the above code works, when I run your code, I get several indentation errors, some symbols that are missing, and at places you have used `pd.Time` but pandas doesn't have any attribute called `Time`, please upload the code, that executes without errors, after that we can work on getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = {'id': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
'time_order': ['2019-01-01 0:00:00', '2019-01-01 00:11:00', '2019-01-02 00:04:00', '2019-01-02 00:15:00', '2019-01-03 00:07:00', '2019-01-03 00:10:00']}

df_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

df_data['time_order'] = pd.to_datetime(df_data['time_order'])
df_data['day_order'] = df_data['time_order'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df_data['time'] = df_data['time_order'].dt.strftime('%H:%M:%S')

x = '00:00:00'
y = '00:15:00'
s = '00:00:00'

tw = 900
begin = pd.Timestamp(s).to_pydatetime()



for k in range(10): # 10 times shift will happen
    begin1 = begin + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(k*60))
    last = begin1 + datetime.timedelta(seconds=int(tw))
    x = begin1.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    y = last.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
    print('\n========\n',x,y)
    
    diff = (pd.Timedelta(y)-pd.Timedelta(x))/2
    df_data2 = df_data[(last>=pd.to_datetime(df_data['time'])) & (pd.to_datetime(df_data['time'])>begin1)].copy()
    #print(df_data2)
    
    df_data2['diff'] = abs(df_data2['time'] - (diff + pd.Timedelta(x)))
    
    mins = df_data2.groupby('day_order').apply(lambda z: z[z['diff']==min(z['diff'])])

    mins.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

    print(mins)
```

Output after first 10 shifts:

```
========
 00:00:00 00:15:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:03:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:04:00  2019-01-02  00:04:00 0 days 00:03:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:07:00  2019-01-03  00:07:00 0 days 00:00:30

========
 00:01:00 00:16:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:02:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:04:00  2019-01-02  00:04:00 0 days 00:04:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:07:00  2019-01-03  00:07:00 0 days 00:01:30
3   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:01:30

========
 00:02:00 00:17:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:01:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:04:00  2019-01-02  00:04:00 0 days 00:05:30
2   0 2019-01-02 00:15:00  2019-01-02  00:15:00 0 days 00:05:30
3   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:00:30

========
 00:03:00 00:18:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:00:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:15:00  2019-01-02  00:15:00 0 days 00:04:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:00:30

========
 00:04:00 00:19:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:00:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:15:00  2019-01-02  00:15:00 0 days 00:03:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:01:30
========
 00:05:00 00:20:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:01:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:15:00  2019-01-02  00:15:00 0 days 00:02:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:02:30

========
 00:06:00 00:21:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:02:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:15:00  2019-01-02  00:15:00 0 days 00:01:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:03:30

========
 00:07:00 00:22:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:03:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:15:00  2019-01-02  00:15:00 0 days 00:00:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:04:30

========
 00:08:00 00:23:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:04:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:15:00  2019-01-02  00:15:00 0 days 00:00:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:05:30

========
 00:09:00 00:24:00
   id          time_order   day_order      time            diff
0   0 2019-01-01 00:11:00  2019-01-01  00:11:00 0 days 00:05:30
1   0 2019-01-02 00:15:00  2019-01-02  00:15:00 0 days 00:01:30
2   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:06:30
```

Now if you see, there were some iteration where there were 4 rows generated in output. If you see in the `diff` column you would find that, there could be pairs of rows that can have same time difference. This is due to the fact that we are considering positive and negative time difference as same.

So for example in the above output, the second iteration i.e. `00:01:00 to 00:16:00` we can see that there are two entries for `2019-01-03`

```
2   0 2019-01-03 00:07:00  2019-01-03  00:07:00 0 days 00:01:30
3   0 2019-01-03 00:10:00  2019-01-03  00:10:00 0 days 00:01:30
```

And this is because both of their difference are of `00:01:30`.
The mid for this range will be at `00:01:00` + `00:07:30` = `00:08:30`

```
00:07:30 <----(- 01:30)----00:08:30---(+ 01:30)--->00:10:00
```

And that's why both orders were displayed